# Can't find (other web locations) option in Microsoft OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am trying to share Microsoft OneNote with Microsoft Team OneNote, but can't find the option (Other Web Locations) I only see the [enter image description here] which takes me to my local computer [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zorBn.png) I was supposed to see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22ZkE.png) this picture in order to go to Web.

Comment: Adding the steps in answer. Try the same and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Steps are documented [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-onenote-for-the-web-to-share-notes-with-other-people-d3481fbe-e06c-4883-b7e9-b2ee9f38aed3). Follow the steps:

1. In OneNote for the web, open the notebook you want to share.
2. Click File > Share > Share with People.
3. In the left column, under Share, make sure Invite people is selected.
4. In the To box, type the email address of the person you want to invite and add recipents to share
5. When you’re ready to send your notebook invitation, click Share